# Ubuntu 14.04.02 hangs after mounting EXT4-fs partition

Tags: 14.04

I have this problem faced several times and I keep reinstalling ubuntu thinking the OS went bad for whatever reasons. I have 14.04.02 LTS server installed. I have virtualized the server using KVM. Everything was working fine. I installed few of the softwares like openvpn, openldap, DNS etc. I had to reboot the server, when I did I started getting plymouth respawing errors. I suppressed this my adding sleep 2 to the plymouth-upstart config file as stated in one of the blogs. This got rid of the errors but the booting went slow, after some time I got /tmp not available error. I followed the blog to resolve the same. Since then, the server hangs on boot after EXT4-fs partition is mounted. I dont want to reinstall the OS and start from scratch. Any help?